# .jar files do not open on double click. But opens in command line

Tags: jar

Before the question, here is the program...

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class jar{
public void show(){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is a test");
    }
}
```

I created a jar file of this program and when I execute it from command prompt, the program runs perfectly.

However, when I double click the jar file, nothing happens. Why does this happen?

Comment: How you run it from command line?

Comment: If the double click doesn't work, then the .jar extension is registered properly in your operating system.

Comment: I run it from the command line using the command java -jar.test.jar

test.jar is the name of the jar file that I created

Answer (score 0):

When you double click the "jar", the OS tries to open it up with its registered program. For example, if you open it up with a "winzip", you are obviously interested  to see whats inside the jar, rather than execute it. However, if you want the program to be executed after a double click, make "java" executable as the default program.

[image: DEFAULT PROGRAM]

Comment: but how do I make "java" executable as the default program?

Comment: On a windows system, right click on the jar, click on "Open With" and select "java" as the program. "java" can be found in your JDK installation "bin" folder.

Comment: well...I have made the default program javaw.exe.. and also tried java.exe from the bin folder....unfortunately does not work

Comment: Well...I solved the problem actually... I downloaded a software called jarfix https://johann.loefflmann.net/downloads/jarfix.exe from this site and run the application. This solved the problem